# Shell script to check url

Tags: directory, scripts, text

I am trying to write a shell script to check for the existence of a particular directory in a particular domain name. For example, I have a web site named `www.example.com`. I want to check whether the page `www.example.com/testpage` exists or not. I have a text file containing a list of directory names,one per line, which must be replaced with the name `testpage`. I want the script to select each of these directory names,append it to the url `www.example.com` and validate it. How can I begin writing my script?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924422/how-do-i-determine-if-a-web-page-exists-with-shell-scripting, especially this [script](https://gist.github.com/igilham/12eb33ab8a86f1e815d2)

Answer (score 2):

Let's examine an example.

File `relative_urls.list`:

```
> cat relative_urls.list 
/users/449/oli
/users/449
/help/badges
/help/badges/185/curious
/unanswered
/questions/tagged/12.04
/questions/tagged/boot
/questions/tagged/oracle
/questions/tagged/internet_explorer
/questions/tagged/outlook
```

We'd like to check if these documents available on the site http://askubuntu.com.

Possible solution:

```
> cat relative_urls.list |while read i ; do curl --head -s "http://askubuntu.com"$i |grep -q '^HTTP.*200' && echo "OK '$i'" ||echo "fail '$i'" ; done
```

And the result is:

```
OK '/users/449/oli'
fail '/users/449'
OK '/help/badges'
OK '/help/badges/185/curious'
OK '/unanswered'
OK '/questions/tagged/12.04'
OK '/questions/tagged/boot'
OK '/questions/tagged/oracle'
fail '/questions/tagged/internet_explorer'
fail '/questions/tagged/outlook'
```

If you prefer another definition of availability of url, you can change `grep` command to something more relevant to your conditions.

Important thing is that `curl` shows whether an url is *served* by a web server. There is no reliable method to determine *existence of directory* on a web server's file system via http.

Comment: +1, but use `stdin` redirection instead of `cat`:  `< relative_urls.list while [...]`